# Trigger firing on every update instead of just one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have a trigger in MySQL table. Table has about 20 columns.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `completion_date_update`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `orders`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.`order_status` = 'COMPLETED' THEN
    SET NEW.`completion_date` = NOW();
  END IF;

  IF NEW.`order_status` != 'COMPLETED' THEN
    SET NEW.`completion_date` = NULL;
  END IF;
END$$
```

What I want is this trigger to update `completion_date` column **only** when column `order_status` is updated. If any other column is updated this trigger should not do anything.
What is actually happening is this trigger is updating `completion_date` upon any column update.

Can anyone explain to me why does this happen and what did I do wrong?

`order_status` column is NOT NULL and has possible values as below:

```
enum('NEW','OPEN','COMPLETED','CANCELLED','REPLACED')
```

Default is `'NEW'`

Thanks

Comment: is `order_status` nullable? the trigger fires if the the value of the column is already marked as `completed` and you are only upting on the other column?

Comment: It's a ENUM with 5 different options. I just set it as NOT NULL. I'll test it now.

Comment: @JW. I've just updated my question with `order_status` column details.

Comment: @JW. That was it :) `(NEW.order_status <> OLD.order_status)` did the trick. Thank you. Should you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should also compare if `order_status` has been changed and that the new value is `COMPLETED`

```
IF (NEW.order_status <> OLD.order_status) AND (NEW.order_status = 'COMPLETED') THEN 
    SET NEW.completion_date = NOW();
END IF;
```

and you can remove the other `IF` below.

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it :)